# Using .htaccess redirect a site root to a site subfolder

Tags: configuration, .htaccess, redirect

I want to be able to redirect my visitors from `http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/blog`.

How can I do that, I saw some examples but any of them works for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://example.com/blog
```

Or for more complex and conditional redirections [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/blog [L,R=301]
```

Both do exactly the same but mod_rewrite may not always be available.