# .htaccess domain language redirect to folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this situation:

- When somebody goes to www.example.com, it should display www.example.com/en/
- When somebody goes to www.example.fr, it should display www.example.com/fr/

Can you help me with htaccess setup?

Thank you guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using .htaccess redirect a site root to a site subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766079/using-htaccess-redirect-a-site-root-to-a-site-subfolder)

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution for .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/fr/ [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/en/ [L,R=301]
```